# make a circle shape which will later turn into a shape that resembles a half circle and there are orders on both sides

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, shapes

i want to make a shape like this with html, css, js
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr2t3.png)
a shape that was originally only a circle and changed to form a half line that forms a semicircle with a border radius on both sides.
i just want to make it with html, css and js. What code do I need to generate the code and animation.

```css
.shape {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.shape::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.shape::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.shape.hide-semi-circle::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `.shape` needs to be a square; set its position as `relative` (just ignore the variables). We'll need to `absolute`-ly position its `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

```css
.shape {
    position: relative;
    height: var(--size);
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

Then, styles those. Note how `border-` properties are used.

```css
.shape::before, .shape::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    border: var(--border) solid var(--color);
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: var(--size) var(--size) 0 0;
}
```

Flip `::after` 180 degrees around the x-axis. Add a `.hover` rule so that its `opacity` changes when we hover over `.shape`.

```css
.shape::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: calc(var(--size) / 2) calc(var(--size) / 2);
  transition: opacity var(--duration);
}

.shape:hover::after {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Finally, to make the ends look curvy, use another child element and style it so that it becomes a circle with the same color:

```css
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - var(--border) / 2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: var(--border);
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    background: var(--color);
    box-shadow: calc(var(--size) - var(--border)) 0 var(--color);
}
```

Try it:

```css
.shape {
  --size: 100px;
  --border: 10px;
  --color: #f00;
  --duration: 0.5s;
}

.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--size);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.shape::before,
.shape::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: var(--border) solid var(--color);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: var(--size) var(--size) 0 0;
}

.shape::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: calc(var(--size) / 2) calc(var(--size) / 2);
  transition: opacity var(--duration);
}

.shape:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - var(--border) / 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--border);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: var(--color);
  box-shadow: calc(var(--size) - var(--border)) 0 var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="dot">
</div>
```